# How can I make this code work with generics?

Tags: java, generics

I have some code that sorts a stack using only another stack (it's an interview question).  The code itself seems to work.  I'd like to implement it using generics, so that any kind of stack is sortable, under the following conditions:

1. The sort method remains static (I'd like to avoid parameterizing the entire class)
2. I can use native comparator operators (like <) - I guess the parameterized type needs to implement [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).

Is this possible?

Here's the code.

```
import java.util.Stack;
public class StackSort {
    static void sort(Stack<Integer> stack) {
        Stack<Integer> tmp = new Stack<Integer>();
        for (;;) {
            int nswaps = 0;
            while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
                Integer curr = stack.pop();
                if (!stack.isEmpty() && curr < stack.peek()) {
                    Integer next = stack.pop();
                    tmp.push(next);
                    tmp.push(curr);
                    ++nswaps;
                } else {
                    tmp.push(curr);
                }
            }
            while (!tmp.isEmpty()) {
                stack.push(tmp.pop());
            }
            if (nswaps == 0) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();
        stack.push(6);
        stack.push(4);
        stack.push(11);
        stack.push(8);
        stack.push(7);
        stack.push(3);
        stack.push(5);
        System.out.println(stack);
        StackSort.sort(stack);
        System.out.println(stack);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, your 2nd point is not possible(Java does not support Operator Overloading), rest is possible. Have you tried implementing it?

Comment: You'll need to make some minor adjustments if you want to use `Comparable` (since operator overloading is not supported in Java). That is, you should replace `curr < stack.peek()` with `curr.compareTo(stack.peek()) < 0`.

Comment: Ah, thanks for reminding me about Java and operator overloading.  I had a feeling I was asking for the impossible...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right way by mentioning Comparable.

Your method can be

```
static <T extends Comparable<T>>void sort(Stack<T> stack) {
```

And the comparison curr < stack.peek() replace by

```
curr.compareTo(stack.peek()) < 0
```

Comment: for best results use `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`

Answer (score 2):

Using comparator operators on Objects (wrapped primitives or not) is not possible in Java. C++ support such a possibility. However, you can create a workaround by forceing the parameter type to implement Comparable. Your signature should look like this:

```
public <T extends Comparable<? super T>> static void sort(Stack<T> stack)
```

And to compare, use `compareTo` instead of native operators (which is not possible in Java):

```
obj1.compareTo(obj2)
```

Comment: Thanks to @user1666090 (+1) for the correct generics. I forgot the extra `<T>` behind `Comparable`.

Comment: for best results use `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`

Comment: @newacct: Didn't you mean extends, instead of super? Extends seems more logic and correct, compared to super, I think.

Comment: Nope, you are right. Yes. I'll add. Thanks for learning me something! :D